# Stop VScode automatically creating jupyter notebooks when using interactive window

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I typically use the python interactive window to explore scripts. Since one of the updates, however, this now automatically generate a .ipynb notebook in whichever directory I am in, cluttering the file system.

Is there a way to use the interactive window without it automatically creating a .ipynb file?